# Versioning an android app with multiple flavors

Tags: android, versioning

I'm trying to figure out a good way to version my android app.
Problem is that we have multiple environments:

- Standard production environment for most of the users
- Beta environment so users can see the latest additions (WIP)
- Test environment which is an internal release of the app so our own people can use the system.

All 3 environments will have both debug and release, release will be the default that is being used. The debug is only in case there are issues we can't figure out and might be hardware related as this app will be used on our specified devices (so not every device can use it, I mean they could but it might not work as expected).

So I don't know what versioning to use as basically a feature is released only to the test environment, so our internal users can test it.
Once that feature is accepted as a good working feature without bugs or anything (or atleast as low possible) we release it in the beta environment so our customer can give their own thought about this feature so we can get an idea of our customer requirements.
Once we gather that information we compile it and then discuss if we should implement it in our production environment, once it has been accepted as a new feature, we launch it to our production environment.

So because we don't update our production environment that frequently as it has to get through test and beta environment, I am wondering what might be a good versioning system for this?

I know that many use the "major.minor.patch" versioning but I don't know if this will work in this case.

Any ideas?

### My thought:

I was thinking to maybe use "major.minor.patch" versioning of production and for the beta and test environment I would do "major.minor.patch-environment-major.minor.patch" so we can see how many changes we have applied to it since the last update to production.

But I don't know if that's a good idea or not...

Answer (score 2):

You can give version to each flavors separately like below

```
productFlavors {
 Standard{
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0.0"
 }
 Beta {
   versionCode 2
   versionName "1.2.0"
 }
 Test {
   versionCode 3
   versionName "1.3.0"
 }
}
```

inside app level build.gradel

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but then I was thinking that this might be confusing. Because if you add Feature A to Beta its version would be 1.3.0 and it gets accepted and you release it to standard it would update to version 1.1.0. Meaning that standard 1.1.0 is nearly equal to beta 1.3.0. . Hence I was thinking it might be confusing that there might be such a difference in versioning...

Comment: I might just be me. Because I think that beta is based on production + extra feature and fixes. Hence I tend to think that the version should have some form of connection in between them.